# Moving row to different sheet in google sheets from dropdown app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have tried this script and it does move the row to the right destination sheet, but if you need to change it back it will delete a row in the original sheet.  I do know I need to make the row count a variable, but my main issue has been getting this to work without deleting rows.  I have another script but it is without a loop and only works for sheet1.  Any help would be appreciated here, thank you. I've only set it up as 5 columns in the table example

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const ss = sh.getActiveSheet();

  var dest;
  if (ss.getName() == 'sheet1' && e.value == 'Done') {
    dest = sh.getSheetByName('sheet1 Archive');
  }else if (ss.getName() == 'sheet1 Archive' && e.value != 'Done') {
    dest = sh.getSheetByName('sheet1');
  } else if (ss.getName() == 'sheet2' && e.value == 'Done') {
    dest = sh.getSheetByName('sheet2 Archive');
  } else if (ss.getName() == 'sheet2 Archive' && e.value != 'Done') {
    dest = sh.getSheetByName('sheet2');
  } else if (ss.getName() == 'sheet3' && e.value == 'Done') {
    dest = sh.getSheetByName('sheet3 Archive');
  } else if (ss.getName() == 'sheet3 Archive' && e.value != 'Done') {
    dest = sh.getSheetByName('sheet3');
  } else return;

  var rData = dest.getRange(1, 1, dest.getLastRow()).getValues();
  var dr = 0;
  for (dr; dr < rData.length; dr++) {
    if (rData[dr][0] == '') break;
  }
  dr++;
  var r = e.range.rowStart;
  ss.getRange(r, 1, 1, 11).copyTo(dest.getRange(dr, 1, 1, 11));
  ss.deleteRow(e.range.rowStart);
}
```

sheet1

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | Status (dropdowns) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 6 | 7 | 8 | Live |
| 5 | 7 | 8 | 9 | Live |
| 6 | 8 | 9 | 10 | Done (will move to sheet1 Archive and delete) |
| 7 | 9 | 10 | 11 | Done (will move to sheet1 Archive and delete) |
| 8 | 10 | 11 | 12 | Live |

sheet1 Archive

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | Status (dropdowns) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 8 | 9 | 10 | Done (can be moved back when other "done" deselected) |
| 7 | 9 | 10 | 11 | Done (can be moved back when other "done" deselected) |

Comment: Might the row to be move have formatting or other attributes besides the values that need to copied or you are only interested in the values?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the good question, I'm only interested in the values as of right now

Comment: Your question can be greatly improved if you add a table to the question. [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) are a better alternative than spreadsheets to show your data structure.  If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet to avoid closure of your question, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455/) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Comment: Thank you, I haven't had to upload like that before, thank you for the heads up on it.  I took it down and will work this in when back at computer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Try it this way:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast("Entry");
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e))
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const a = ["Sheet0"];//You can added more sheets 
  const b = ["Sheet1"];//ddestinations and sources have to be in same column
  const idx0 = a.indexOf(sh.getName());
  const idx1 = b.indexOf(sh.getName());

  if (~idx0 && e.range.columnStart == 2 && e.range.rowStart > 1 && e.value == "Done") {
    e.source.toast("0")
    let sh = e.source.getSheetByName(a[idx0]);
    let dsh = e.source.getSheetByName(b[idx0]);
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1,sh.getLastColumn()).copyTo(dsh.getRange(dsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1));
    sh.deleteRow(e.range.rowStart);
  }
  if (~idx1 && e.range.columnStart == 2 && e.range.rowStart > 1 && e.value != "Done") {
    e.source.toast("1");
    let dsh = e.source.getSheetByName(a[idx1]);
    let sh = e.source.getSheetByName(b[idx1]);
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, sh.getLastColumn()).copyTo(dsh.getRange(dsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1));
    sh.deleteRow(e.range.rowStart);
  }
}
```

Sheet0:

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 |  | 6 | 7 | 8 |
| 5 |  | 7 | 8 | 9 |
| 6 |  | 8 | 9 | 10 |
| 7 |  | 9 | 10 | 11 |
| 8 |  | 10 | 11 | 12 |
| 9 |  | 11 | 12 | 13 |
| 10 |  | 12 | 13 | 14 |
| 11 |  | 13 | 14 | 15 |
| 12 |  | 14 | 15 | 16 |
| 13 |  | 15 | 16 | 17 |
| 14 |  | 16 | 17 | 18 |
| 15 |  | 17 | 18 | 19 |
| 16 |  | 18 | 19 | 20 |
| 17 |  | 19 | 20 | 21 |
| 18 |  | 20 | 21 | 22 |
| 19 |  | 21 | 22 | 23 |
| 20 |  | 22 | 23 | 24 |
| 4 | UnDone | 6 | 7 | 8 |
| 1 | Undone | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| 2 | Undone | 4 | 5 | 6 |

Sheet 1:

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 |  | 7 | 8 | 9 |
| 6 |  | 8 | 9 | 10 |
| 7 |  | 9 | 10 | 11 |
| 8 |  | 10 | 11 | 12 |
| 9 |  | 11 | 12 | 13 |
| 10 |  | 12 | 13 | 14 |
| 11 |  | 13 | 14 | 15 |
| 12 |  | 14 | 15 | 16 |
| 13 |  | 15 | 16 | 17 |
| 14 |  | 16 | 17 | 18 |
| 15 |  | 17 | 18 | 19 |
| 16 |  | 18 | 19 | 20 |
| 17 |  | 19 | 20 | 21 |
| 18 |  | 20 | 21 | 22 |
| 19 |  | 21 | 22 | 23 |
| 20 |  | 22 | 23 | 24 |
| 3 | Done | 5 | 6 | 7 |
| 3 | Done | 5 | 6 | 7 |

Comment: If you get a chance the bitwise not operator what exactly is that doing in this?  Checking for the opposite, coinciding entry in the other array?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_NOT

Comment: Thank you again for this, I guess I don't have enough reputation to upvote

Answer (score 0):

As you are interested only on the values, use `Sheet.appendRow` instead of `Sheet.copyTo` / `Sheet.getRange`

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const ss = sh.getActiveSheet();

  var dest;
  if (ss.getName() == 'sheet1' && e.value == 'Done') {
    dest = sh.getSheetByName('sheet1 Archive');
  }else if (ss.getName() == 'sheet1 Archive' && e.value != 'Done') {
    dest = sh.getSheetByName('sheet1');
  } else if (ss.getName() == 'sheet2' && e.value == 'Done') {
    dest = sh.getSheetByName('sheet2 Archive');
  } else if (ss.getName() == 'sheet2 Archive' && e.value != 'Done') {
    dest = sh.getSheetByName('sheet2');
  } else if (ss.getName() == 'sheet3' && e.value == 'Done') {
    dest = sh.getSheetByName('sheet3 Archive');
  } else if (ss.getName() == 'sheet3 Archive' && e.value != 'Done') {
    dest = sh.getSheetByName('sheet3');
  } else return;

  dest.appendRow(ss.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, 11).getValues()[0]);
  ss.deleteRow(e.range.rowStart);
}
```

Comment: Oh nice, I see what you're saying though, that also overwrites the dropdown in the destination sheet.  But the actual line doesn't disappear like before.. Is there a way to keep the dropdowns intact?  Thank you btw it won't let me like this solution

Comment: @jrgoose I think that the destination row hasn't the dropdows. Add them in advance to the whole column in both sheets.